# How to compress elements from an array as much as possible?

Tags: algorithm, compression

There is a sorted array **A** of around 200 elements, there are no duplicates. There is a second array **B** with 30 elements, one element may occur at most 2 times. All the elements of **B** are from **A**.

For example,

- A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 199];
- B = [2, 2, 5, 8, 9, 11, 11, 20, 20, ...];

How can **B** be represented with a string as short as possible? The string, along with the array **A** needs to be enough to be able to reconstruct the array **B**. I'm planning on using base 62.

First, I gave each element a 2 digit id based on their index and add a character that is not part of the alphabet to the end of the id if there are 2 copies of the element. With this method The string is at most 60 at least 45 characters long.

Then, I converted the array **A** to a base 3 number with as many digits as the length of the array. Every digit corresponds to an index **i**. So the digit is 0, 1 or 2 depending on how many copies of the element at index **i** of **A** is included in **B**. Example: 0001000200022000011... Then the number is converted to base 62. The length of the string depends on the index of the elements but it is usually shorter than the first method. The problem is that as the length of array **A** increases, so does the string.

What would be a better way to make the string even shorter?

EDIT: The order of the elements in **B** doesn't matter.

Comment: Your second method doesn't encode the order of elements in B.  Is B sorted or something so that you don't have to encode this?

Comment: In your 1st method you can encode if a number occurs 2 times in a row in the lowest bit of your 2nd digit (bse62) because 62*31= 1922 is already plenty for the index of array `A`. -> at most 60 at least 30 characters long

Answer (score 2):

Use your 0/1/2 encoding, putting each of those in one *byte*. Use gzip/zlib/zstd or similar compressor on that. Then encode the result in your base-62 encoding. (Why base 62?)

This will use Huffman or ANS coding on the 0/1/2 values, and run-length encoding on long strings of zeros. As A gets longer, but B does not, there will be longer strings of zeros in the result, which will be compressed out.

Using your example A and B (ignoring the ... in B), I get this string with zstd and Base64:

```
KLUv/STIfQAAYoEBgSH7L8wdAQBeFGgCEbuQ9g==
```

If I increase the length of A from 200 to 1,000,000, without changing B, I get:

```
KLUv/aRAQg8AhAAAYoEBgSH7L8wdAQDO/3PQBAIAEAACABAAAgAQAAIAEAACABAAAgAQAAMSCgDrmMRO
```

about twice as long.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple way that works pretty well.  First we'll convert into an array of numbers from 0 to 7 as follows:

1. replace each element of B with its index in A, and sort it.
2. next, replace each new element in B, except the first, with its difference from the previous element.
3. For each difference in B, generate floor(diff/7) 7s and the remainder diff%7.

This will result in less than 60 numbers from 0-7, which you can think of as a 60-digit number in base-8.

Converting this to base-62 will produce at most 30 base-62 characters.

---

Note that you don't have to use exactly base 8.  Base 10 also works fine if that's more convenient for you, and will also produce at most 30 chars.  You can even alternate between base 6 and base 10 and then convert each *pair* into a base-60 char.  I think that should still be around 30 worst case.

Of course, if you can move up to base-64 output (use `-` and `_`), then base-8 is very convenient.